# Return a string between two different substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to retrieve variables from a string.

String looks something like this:

```
"{'_id': ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764'), 'request_id': 99, 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}"
```

I want to retrieve the following values and assign them to variables:

```
objID = 636d855390928b1b0392b764

reqID = 99

timestamp = 2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576
```

The string will follow this format, but obviously the values are random. I have tried using the `import re` library, but because of the `''` characters I don't get the correct results.

I tried

```
objectID= re.findall(r'\'.*?\'', s)
```

to test out how this works this gives me everything between '' in a list. However, I want to get a value between `ObjectId('` and `')`.

I attempted the following:

```
re.findall(r'ObjectId(.+?)',s)
```

But this outputs `(`. I try to get the '' marks in, but I always get an error no matter how I try to include them.

Comment: Why do you have a dictionary rendered as a string?  If it were still a dictionary this would be super easy. Find the spot in your code where you built a dictionary and put a `str()` around it, and then remove the `str()`.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/478746) (funnily enough, it looks an awful lot like the example of an XY Problem from the top answer to that FAQ). Could you elaborate on why you need to dissect a string in this way? There's a good chance that there's a simpler solution to the "bigger problem" that doesn't involve re-investing parsing with regexs.

Comment: So the reason why I need to dissect a string is the input will come in as a string but it wont always be a dictionary like @Samwise mentioned. Sometimes it might be a portion out of a log file, sometimes it might be a string from another function. But it will always have for example ```ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764')```. So I would like to parse said mystery string and get that value/other values and do stuff with them downstream.

Answer (score 1):

Without regex you can use `namedtuple` and `eval`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

# Small subset functions of MongoDB
context = {
    'ObjectId': namedtuple('ObjectId', ['value']),
    'ISODate': namedtuple('ISODate', ['value'])
}

s = "{'_id': ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764'), 'request_id': 99, 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}"

d = eval(s, context)
```

Output:

```
>>> d
{'_id': ObjectId(value='636d855390928b1b0392b764'),
 'request_id': 99,
 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}

>>> d['_id']
ObjectId(value='636d855390928b1b0392b764')

>>> d['_id'].value
'636d855390928b1b0392b764'
```

**Note**: it's also possible to parse the expression tree with `ast` module and `NodeTransformer` to replace a `Call` function like `ObjectID` by a `Constant` but it's a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the input to a dictionary using re.split and a bit of stripping:

```
import re

S = "{'_id': ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764'), 'request_id': 99, 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}"

KV = iter(re.split(r"('(?:[^']*?)':)",S)[1:])
D  = { k[1:-2]:v.strip("' ,}") for k,v in zip(KV,KV) }

print(D)

{'_id': "ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764')", 
 'request_id': '99', 
 'timestamp': '2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576'}
```

Then access the values by name from the dictionary:

```
D["request_id"]  #  '99'
```

It is also possible to assign the values directly to variables if they are always in the same order:

```
_, _id, request_id, timestamp = ( v.strip("' ,}") 
                                  for v in re.split(r"'(?:[^']*?)':",S))

print(_id)        # ObjectId('636d855390928b1b0392b764')
print(request_id) # 99
print(timestamp)  # 2022-11-10T18:12:19.273576
```

*Note that, in this last example, the pattern does not have an enclosing capturing group because we don't need the keywords*